# JPS command not showing all the working daemons of hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop via cygwin in window 7 .All daemons of hadoop has started but jps failed to show tasktraker,secondarynamenode,datanode. I checked in logs , all are working fine. What could be the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to browse through the NameNode and JobTracker webUI? Please show us your logs.

Comment: ya i can able to browse